# XML Response not showing in GWT from external SOLR server?

Tags: xml, gwt, solr

I have developed a GWT application and also installed a Apache Solr Server on the localhost machine.

The Solr is working fine and the queries are returning the desired results.

Now for embedding the results in my GWT application I am sending a http request using GWT's RequestBuilder to the Solr server.

The query is reaching on the Solr as I can view it in the command prompt.

On the GWT side the request is successful as my `onResponseRecieved()` is called. But the size of the response is 0 and also the status code is 0.

I am unable to find where is the problem.

Also, if there is a Same Origin Policy then the `onError()` method should be run but it isn't.

Following is my sending and handling code

```
String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=bname:"+whatBox.getText()+"&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on";
        RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode(url));
        System.out.println("here");
        try{
            Request req = rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                    System.out.println("in res");
                    System.out.println(response.getHeadersAsString());
                    RootPanel.get("content").clear();
                    RootPanel.get("content").add(new Label(response.getText()));    
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            });

        }catch(RequestException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are violating [SOP rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules). To avoid them, I would recommend you using [JsonpRequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html) not using `RequestBuilder`s. And also take a look a very useful community wiki: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) and  [How the Same Origin Policy does affect GWT?](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_SOP)